# coding ndk main() with lots of includes

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I have tried a simple NDK C++ (quite different syntax from C!) hello world and it works.

Now I want to compile my very large C++ file with the NDK.

Do I need to rename my `main()`?  I have noticed a few post that use `android_main()`, or should I use the standard package.class.method? And surround them with Excellent! It works like this:

```
extern "C" {
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
  Java_com_optimuse_app_OptimuseAppActivity_generate(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz){}
```

But can I rename my main to something like this? Or should I use android_main. The many posts on the internet are confusing me.

Also, I am not sure what I need to do with all my includes. I have a bunch like `<algorithm.h>` and my own .h files.

Thank you for helping me with the conventions.

Comment: concerning the libraries. Even is I add APP_STL := stlport_static  to the Android.mk, I he cannot find iostream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it to work: I ommitted my .h files from the Mk file. And I added this at the bottom of main (renamed to main1) it from java:

```
extern "C" {

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_optimuse_MainActivity_generate(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz);
};

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_optimuse_MainActivity_generate(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz){

    string str = main1();
    return env->NewStringUTF(str.c_str());

}
```